# Why I can't reorder auto increment mysql table with bash script?

Tags: mysql, bash

I want to reorder my table id. I have try with 2 different ways, from MySQL command and from my bash script. But why my bash script can't reorder by id?
Here is my code :

```
First try :
echo "set @num=0" | mysql -D$db -u$user -h$host -p$pass
echo "update list set id=@num:=(@num+1)" | mysql -D$db -u$user -h$host -p$pass
echo "alter table list AUTO_INCREMENT=1" | mysql -D$db -u$user -h$host -p$pass

Second try :
mysql -D$db -u$user -p$pass -h$host "set @num=0"
mysql -D$db -u$user -p$pass -h$host "update list set id=@num:=(@num+1)"
mysql -D$db -u$user -p$pass -h$host "alter table list AUTO_INCREMENT=1"
```

Every time I use that code in my bash script, it give me error like this :

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 1: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

But it doesn't show when I directly use MySQL from my terminal. And I'm really sure that I don't have any '0' value in my ID.
How can it happen? and how to solve it?
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this by writing the commands to a file like so:

(auto.sql - dont forget the semi colons at the end of each line)

```
set @num=0;
update list set id=@num:=(@num+1);
alter table list AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Save the file and then run your mysql with the .sql file as an input:

```
 mysql -uusername -ppassword database < auto.sql
```